# NSLog Timestamps in Xcode Organizer's Console Don't Show Milliseconds

Tags: ios, xcode, nslog, organizer

I am using `NSLog` to record logs in an iPhone application.

In Xcode when I execute my iPhone application with "Run -> Console," I get timestamps in the following format:  "2011-06-06 18:34:58.189".  When I view the console through the Xcode Organizer, the timestamps are in the following format:  "Jun  6 18:42:51".  Is there any way to ensure that the timestamps displayed in the Xcode Organizer display milliseconds?

Or would I need to write my own logging function instead of using `NSLog`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the method described here ([http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/01/09/redirect-nslog-to-a-file-on-the-iphone/)](http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/01/09/redirect-nslog-to-a-file-on-the-iphone/) to redirect stderr to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a utility I developed called [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger). It is much more flexible than plain `NSLog`, and should be able to be configured to display millisecond-precision timestamps.

Comment: I edited your answer to include more information about what you linked to. I only took a brief look, though, so please correct it if it's wrong.